# JSON - Django/Webdatarocks: unable to correctly serialize data in JSON

Tags: json, django, serialization, webdatarocks

I currently develop a Django project and try to implement WebDataRocks
WebDataRocks is a free web reporting tool for data analysis and visualization

I works but my problem deal with correctly presenting data to be updated in Webdatarocks
I would like to update each of my models.

I have a views name data use with my template that load WebDataRocks

```
def data(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", mymodel.objects.filter(med_ide__lte=10))
return render(request, 'myapp/data.html', {'data':data})
```

I do not really understand the way json is produce because I get this format:

```
[
    {
        "model": "myapp.mymodel", 
        "pk": 1, 
        "fields": 
            {
               "var1": 1, 
               "var2": "ABC", 
               "var3": "code", 
               "var4": "text", 
               "var5": null, 
               "var6": "'text'", 
               "var7": null
             }
     }, 
     {
        "model": "myapp.mymodel", 
        ....
     }
]
```

[image]

The only 2 variables I get access in webdatarocks table are myapp.mymodel and pk
I try to extract only part of my data I need (=fields) using things like data['fields'] but it is not the right syntax

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you must get fields value from json, like data.get('fields') and then send it in context.

Comment: thansk for replying. I try data = serializers.serialize("json", Medicament.objects.filter(med_ide__lte=10)).get('med_dru','med_num') but I get an error 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I also try values method to extract part I am interested on : data = serializers.serialize("json", Medicament.objects.filter(med_ide__lte=10).values('med_ide','med_num','med_dru')) but get an other error 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: I controle type of data like this and it is a QuerySet

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/WorldlyPushyLicense you can manipulate with dict like this

Comment: object return with serializers.serialize is not a list so that your solution do  not work; I try to cast into list but the same

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (don't if it is a good solution but seems to work) using a list pass to the context instead of using serializer
data = json.dumps(list(Medicament.objects.filter(med_ide__lte=10).values('med_ide','med_num','med_dru')))

I can use values() method to extract fields I need