# Django - Query: how to decode integer field value with its string value 'on the fly'

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

maybe it is not good practice but I would like to know if it is possible to decode an integer field value with its string value 
I know I should have a specific models linked as thesaurus...

I have a models mymodel
I produce a QuerySet mymodel.objects.values('id','var2','var3','var4') for example
var3 is an integer (0/1) for Yes/No answer

Is it possible to populate my QuerySet with Yes or No instead of its integer value?

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate it, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When

QuerySet.objects.values('id', 'var2', 'var4',
    new_var3=Case(
        When(var3=1, then=Value('Yes')),
        default=Value('No'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

Note that you however should rename the variable.

That being said, it is *not* a good idea to use `.values(..)` or `.values_list(..)` to eprform serialization. Furthermore it will perform text processing on the database, and often that is not really the *core task* of a database. Normally [*serializers* [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) are used for that.

Comment: I don't know if you have seen my other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768702/json-django-webdatarocks-unable-to-correctly-serialize-data-in-json) but serializer.serialize result do not correspond to the format I need... reason why I use values...

Comment: @SLATER: By declaring a serializer (subclass, just like you subclass from models, forms, etc.), you can specify the format. The standard serializers is just a "best effort"). Furthermore a serializers does not specify the target "language" (like JSON), it can encode to JSON, CSV, XML, etc.